# Create DHCP for 1000 Users

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp

Currently we are running windows server 2003 with static ip for 200 users ,now the organiszation is about to expand so atleast 1000 people will be working, so i needed to create a DHCP for 1000 users.

Possible way is creating superscope and joing this superscopes or only changing the subnet like 192.168.1.255 192.168.2.255, 192.168.3.255 192.168.4
.255 follwed by subnet 255.255.242.0. is my option is correct. problem is i have not worked on creating superscopes at all. please help me out.

Comment: If you are planning a network infrastructure for 1000 staff and already getting stuck here, it may be time to do some more planning and/or get some external help.  Also, Server 2003 is end of life and its long past time to get rid of it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need superscopes to make a larger subnet.  Just set everything (including your dhcp server) to use the proper subnet mask.  It would be more common to use something like 172.16.0.0/16, but you can pick whatever you want in the private address spaces.

Beware that using 192.168.x.x addresses may cause you headaches with some VPN setups since most home routers use those addresses - not impossible to work around but more work.

For a 1000 computer network though, you probably want to break things into separate VLANs with separate subnets.